# Como fazer um filtro por categorias no php?

Tags: php, html

Boa tarde galera, sou novato na programação web e estou fazendo uma agenda online onde um aluno cadastra uma prova ou trabalho que terá e em seguida (através do CRUD) o site mostra as provas e trabalhos cadastrados.
Porém, estou com dificuldades em fazer uma tela de categorias.
No meu banco de dados tem os seguintes campos: id_avaliacao, disciplina_avaliacao, materia_avaliacao, professor_avaliacao, categoria_avaliacao e nota_avaliacao.
Eu gostaria de ter um menu na página categorias.php e no menu ter os campos de categoria: artes, matematica, português etc... e quando o usuario clicar em algum campo, o site mostrasse as provas da categoria selecionada.

Comment: a categoria seria a `disciplina_avaliacao` ?

Comment: Na verdade não, pois o usuario ao digitar o campo de disciplina no cadastro, a string iria com letras maiúsculas e pontuações. Então a categiria seria categoria_avaliacao que no caso seria a mesma string do campo disciplina, porém com formatação para banco de dados.

Comment: Então no caso de uma disciplina chamada `Programação`, na disciplina_avaliacao iria como `Programação` e categoria_avaliacao como `programacao`, seria isso ?

Comment: Isso, como no cadastro da avaliação o campo "Disciplina" está como select, assim que seleciona uma disciplina, logo a categoria terá o nome da disciplina.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Vou tentar te dar uma base pra iniciar.

Envie o nome da categoria através do método `_GET`, a partir daí pode utilizar o código abaixo como uma base.

Lembrando, isto apenas irá pegar o nome da categoria e fazer a chamada do que tem dentro deste campo. Como você tem `disciplina_avaliacao` e `materia_avaliacao`, decidi por uma das duas, porém, pode fazer a utilização do campo que for necessário.

```
<?php
//Primeiro deverá pegar o nome da categoria através do $_GET, aqui, irei definir que o GET já possui um valor fixo pra poder continuar.
$_GET['cat'] = "matematica";

$categoria = $_GET['cat'];

$query = "SELECT * FROM categoria WHERE disciplina_avaliacao = " . $categoria . ";

//Montar a estrutura desejada abaixo

?>
```

Comment: No caso, o menu das categorias está na mesma página que será mostrado os resultados. Então eu gostaria de pegar as informações direto do banco de dados. É necessário ter o _GET?

Comment: Iria fazer isto sem um refresh na página?

Comment: Acho que seria mais fácil com o refresh.

Comment: Certo, então em teoria, terá o menu à esquerda, sempre que clicar, se enviar por exemplo no link `<a href="categorias.php?cat=matematica" title="Matemática" />` poderá pegar o valor através do `_GET`, se quiser fazer via `_POST` terá que criar uma página para cada categoria... Com o `_GET` vai criar apenas uma e utilizar a mesma página para inúmeras categorias. O menu, cabeçalho ou outras informações, coloque como `include()` na ppágina, te poupará MUITO trabalho.

Comment: Se eu quiser fazer um menu lateral na index.php e no menu tiver um ul como o <a href="categorias.php?cat=matematica" title="Matemática" /> posso pegar o valor por _GET e fazer um SELECT * FROM tb_avaliacoes WHERE cat_avaliacao='$categoria'?

Comment: Exatamente, dentro da página `categorias.php` tu vai fazer este select, a partir daí é que toda a mágica acontece. Caso tu esteja trabalhando com um servidor, me avisa que eu posso tentar te ajudar on-line.

Comment: Entendi, estou fazendo cada prova em uma <div class = "card">, após fazer o select, como faço o echo dessa div?
Estou fazendo em localhost mesmo, mas agradeço sua ajuda. Estou fazendo um curso de Desenvolvimento de Sistemas e provavelmente esse será meu TCC kkkkk, por milagre achei esse fórum super acolhedor e com pessoas que tem paciência (assim como você), acredito que terei bastante ajuda nesse fórum, agradeço a atenção.

Comment: Que isso, relax hahaha. Bom, você terá que fazer o seguinte, dentro de cada link passar a url `categorias.php?cat=nomedacategoria`, ele vai abrir a página `categorias.php`, lá dentro desta página, pega o nome da categoria no get `$categorias = $_GET['cat']`, depois que fizer o select, monta a página casa exista esta categoria. P.S.: Se a resposta ajudou, pode voltar nela e marcar como correta por favorzinho? hahaha

Comment: Entendi kkkkk, me ajudou bastante cara. Marco sim, pode deixar. Valeuu!!

Comment: Qualquer coisa, pega o meu e-mail que eu vou te ajudando conforme der fora daqui (jakson1990@gmail.com)

Comment: Opa valeu jakson!!